# JCheckbox does not work in the JTable rather show true and false

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I have created a table to show student and I want get the absent student in this table so I put `JCheckBox` on the table but during the running program, true and false appeared instead of check box. How to solve it?

```
String sql="select id, name, mname,lname from student where stage = "+st+"";

 pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
 rs=pst.executeQuery();

 //jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
   ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
     for (int col = 0; col < rsmd.getColumnCount(); col++) {
     model.addColumn(rsmd.getColumnName(col + 1));
    }
     model.addColumn("Absent");

     while (rs.next()) 
     {
        Vector data = new Vector();
        for (int col = 0; col < rsmd.getColumnCount(); col++) {//add another Column
            data.add(rs.getObject(col + 1));
        }
         data.add(Boolean.FALSE);
         model.addRow(data);
      }

 jTable1.setModel(model);
```

[image]

Comment: Use [renderers and editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in the tutorial which was linked in the first comment.

Comment: Alternative: don't use `DefaultTableModel`. Write your own table model which return correct column class for your columns. For your last column you should return `Boolean.class`

Comment: Thank you very much